# Does the polynomial $z^{n+1} + w^{n+1}$ factor as $(z^n + w^n)f(z,w)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Does the complex polynomial $z^{n+1} + w^{n+1}$ factor as $(z^n + w^n)f(z,w)$? I don’t have any conditions on $f$ apart from that it must be continuous. If the answer is yes, I would appreciate information on how I can obtain $f$.

Comment: Not if $f$ is a polynomial. Try $w=1$ and argue about the zeros.

Comment: If you want $f(z,w)$ to be a polynomial, then the answer is "no".

Comment: $f(z,w)$ can't even be an analytic function on $\mathbb{C}^2$: for example if $z = w \cdot e^{2\pi i/n}$ with $w \ne 0$ then $z^n + w^n = 0$ but $z^{n+1} + w^{n+1} \ne 0$.